# How to center a Bootstrap menu item in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center an item which is a part of the Bootstrap navigation menu.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: yellow; font-size: 30px";>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
       <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
                );
          ?>
         </div>
     </nav>
```

Now, I have 5 items in my WordPress menu. I am trying to make it so, that the navbar-brand is on the left, first menu on the center, three menu-items to its right, and last menu item to the very end.

`|Logo|          |first|         |second||third||fourth|         |fifth|`

The logo, `navbar-brand` is on the left by default and I managed to put the fifth menu-item on the right by doing

```
  .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
    }
```

Now I need to center the first item and then push the rest of the items to a bit right. I tried doing

```
  .menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it done in Bootstrap 4, you need to wrap each of the 3 groups in their own `<ul>` and add the `ml-auto` class to that.

Here's a working HTML snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also note: the `navbar-toggleable-md` class does not exist in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thank you. Now i just need to figure out how to give each group its own ul in wp_nav_menu.